# Example of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem on a non-interval? (3-dim compact set for example)

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, compactness

So I'm familiar with the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem for closed intervals [a, b] but am now looking to prove it for a more general 3-dimensional compact set. That is, if f is continuous on the set X, f can be approximated by a polynomial. Any tips to head in that direction? I'm familiar with the long-ish proof involving proving it works on [0, 1] then generalizing.

Comment: If $f$ can be uniformly approximated on a cell $[a.b]\times[c,d]\times[e,f]$, then $f$ can be uniformly approximated on a compact set, since every compact subset of $\mathbb R^3$ is a subset of such a cell.